# Nodejs built-in debugger shows blank page

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-debugger

I am running node v6.9.1 on OS X.

I am running a script using `sudo node --inspect <script name>`, as described in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.1/docs/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js).

Runs correctly giving message telling me to go to a page to debug.

When I visit this page, I get the frames for the debugger, but no code is displayed.

I have tried disabling all extensions in chrome.

No errors are shown.

Has anyone seen this issue? Would love to be able to debug.

Comment: Please, avoid sudo. Especially when you enable remote debugging.

Comment: @Eugene Why is this especially true with remote debugging?

Comment: Debugger protocols are usually not secure (no authentication, etc). Node.js has full access to your file system as per you current user. If you run it as root, somebody on your network can do with your system anything - launch any application, read or write files, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with my localhost being mapped to a different ip. The url given by node when using --inspect use a localhost. When I manually switched it out with the proper address, the inspector worked.

Hope this helps someone who runs into the same problem